# kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding --clusterrole cluster-admin --user "$(gcloud config get-value account)" throws error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, hpa

I am trying to setup Horizontal pod autoscaler with GKE.

I am following this document to setup autoscaling based on custom metrics

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/autoscaling-metrics

I am stuck with deploying the custom metrics adapter.

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding \
--clusterrole cluster-admin --user "$(gcloud config get-value account)"
```

The above command throws error

> Your active configuration is: [cloudshell-20206]
> error: failed to create clusterrolebinding: Post "http://localhost:8080/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/clusterrolebindings?fieldManager=kubectl-create": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused

I am unable to grant the user the ability to create required authorization roles.

Please point me where am i going wrong

Comment: In order to run kubectl command you need to connect to your cluster. Try to run "kubeclt get nodes" as a test.If that fails then try to connect to your cluster first.

Comment: edit : kubectl get nodes

Comment: yes @dany L got it, thanks. Now i a have completed the setup but autoscaler says unable to read all metrics whereas i can see the metric explorer is showing the values where as the autoscale in workload says unable to read all metrics

Comment: @bngk since the issue posted here was resolved, I recommend you to indicate how it was resolved and close this question followed by the creation of a different question for the new issue. 

However, I've found a possible answer to your issue, according to [this document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/), if some of the pod’s containers do not have the relevant resource request set, CPU utilization for the pod will not be defined and the autoscaler will not take any action for that metric.

Comment: I am glad to hear that you can connect now, if you have a chance accept answer for the benefit of the community. If you are stuck somewhere else it would be better to create a new stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error you are seeing "could" indicate that your are not connected to your cluster. You may use the following command to connect, eg

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials [clustername] --zone us-central1-c --project [project_id]
```